# accessing to config property of my custom service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to access to my custom service into its config property to inject http interceptor like

```
angular
        .module("common.services")        
        .factory("redirectService",
                ["$resource", "$q", "$location", 
                 redirectService]),
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
             $httpProvider.interceptors.push('redirectService');
        });
 function redirectService($resource, $q, $location){
   ...
 }
```

but obviously this is not correct cause I'm getting firebug console error

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' .config(function
>   ($httpProvider) {

Answer (score 3):

remove last `,` from

```
.factory("redirectService",
   ["$resource", "$q", "$location", 
   redirectService]),
```